# Apache rewrite condition for ajax crawling

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, angularjs, seo

I'm trying implement [google ajax crawlable snapshots](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

For this I've added following rewrite conditions in `.htaccess` as follows

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1.html? [NC,L]
```

It works fine but it fails in following situation.

```
www.mysite.com/#!/
```

This is crawled as `www.mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/` as in the google documents.

I have a prepared `index.html` in my snapshots directory to serve such requests

But for the above rewrite condition it is searching for `.html` and that results 403 response. Appreciate if you can help me to fix to serve `index.html` page for such requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an additional rule for above use case. Insert this rule **above your existing rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/index.html? [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /snapshots/%1.html? [NC,L]
```