# The correct way to make a GWT (Ajax) URL crawlable/indexable

Tags: java, ajax, search, gwt, indexing

I have an app that I need search engine crawlers to be able to index. 
I don't need that the whole app to be indexed just specific URL (or URL pattern) like `http://examplegwtapp.com/xyz` where `xyz` is a hash code, similar to those URL shorteners out there.

**My app works like this:**

When that URL is accessed, the servlet will forward the request to a GWT app passing this fragment: `app.html#View?hash=xyz`

So the View page is totally dynamic.

The question is what is the correct way to make this specific dynamically generated URL to be indexed or crawled by search engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/?csw=1)
and [A proposal for making AJAX crawlable](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)

In a nutshell these are the steps you should consider:

1. Crawlers maps from pretty url to ugly url. i.e from
   http://examplegwtapp.com/app.html#View?hash=xyz to
   http://examplegwtapp.com/app.html?_escaped_fragment_=hash=xyz
2. crawler requests the ugly url
3. Server maps from ugly url to pretty url. you can do this by identifying on the apache level any _escaped_fragment_ request and redirect it to a certain server controller to handle the crawler call. i.e. check [Apache rewrite condition for ajax crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180626/apache-rewrite-condition-for-ajax-crawling)
4. Server invokes headless browser(HtmlUnit or if just small portion of your code is js just generate the static html with your server
   code. i.e [HtmlUnit Generate Page for GWT App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012724/1493954)
5. Headless browser response returned to the crawler.